# Ubuntu won't boot without all drives connected & mounted

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive, fstab, sata

I recently revived this old computer with Ubuntu to use it as a local network fileserver and all has worked out well. I've been able to connect all my hard drives laying around and get samba working.

Unfortunately I only have 3 sata ports available on my motherboard and all those three are connected to my hard drives, which leaves my dvd-drive just sitting in the case.

I tried just plugging the sata cable out of one of the drives (not the boot drive) and connect it to the dvd-drive. Ubuntu wouldn't boot and would display the following message:

```
ACPI PCC probe failed
starting version 219
sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] No Caching mode page found
sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write trough
Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type 'journalctl -xb' to view 
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to try 
again to boot into default mode.
```

When I reconnect the drive instead of the dvd-drive I can boot into the desktop again. [`sde]` is ofcourse the drive disconnected
All the drives were setup with `fstab` and this is my fstab:

```
UUID=deviceuuidhere /home/thibaultmaekelbergh/mounts/folder1 ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=deviceuuidhere /home/thibaultmaekelbergh/mounts/folder2 ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=deviceuuidhere /home/thibaultmaekelbergh/mounts/folder3 ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=deviceuuidhere /home/thibaultmaekelbergh/mounts/folder4 ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID=deviceuuidhere /home/thibaultmaekelbergh/mounts/folder5 ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Before I used `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sdb1` etc instead of UUID but I thought UUID might solve the problem and changing `fscheck` option to 0. They both didn't unfortunately.

I'm really stuck on how to be able to switch the cable to the dvd drive when I want, but still being able to boot. Hope someone here can help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you plug in dvd drive in place of a harddisk mounted in `fstab`? If yes comment out that particular harddisk entry from `fstab` and try again.

Comment: @Ron I know that would fix it but that way I'd have to edit the fstab each time I need the dvd drive. I need an option where if the disk is not available Ubuntu just doesn't check or mount it and boots with the dvd instead.

Comment: AFAIK if a device is listed in fstab and not present at boot time, you're in trouble. So, think in reverse. Comment out the device you usually replace and let the boot process sort it out. The side effect is that you will probably have to manually mount said device after boot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `nofail` option in `/etc/fstab`.

The system will not throw an error if some drive is not connected.

You can add it like `defaults, nofail` instead of just `defaults` or use some relevant set of options instead of `defaults`.

Comment: I saw that too but wasn't sure if it was safe to use it. Can I format it like this: defaults, nofail? Or do I need to leave defaults out?

Comment: Consider adding `nobootwait` along with `nofail` to the line concerning the drive you will be disconnecting.  Explanation here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53456/what-is-the-difference-between-nobootwait-and-nofail-in-fstab

Comment: @Thibmaekelbergh Why could it be not safe? That option is exactly what you need, if you detach some drive. Yes, just like `defaults, nofail`.

Comment: You can leave `defaults` in.  Mine goes `....defaults, nobootwait, nofail 0 0`

Comment: @OrganicMarble I see no reason for `nobootwait` in this case, but it won't spoil anything.

Comment: OK.  When I worked to solve this on my pc, man pages were not clear to me on which option was needed.  I put both and it worked for me.

Comment: Adding `nobootwait` and `nobootfail` to the file didn't solve the issue. As a temp fix I just commented out the drive with the least capacity. Thanks for the reply anyway.

Comment: @Thibmaekelbergh It is not `nobootfail`, it is `nofail`.

Comment: @Pilot6 yeah that was a typo. I actually put nofail in the fstab